# How to add ROS icon/ flair to my profile or website?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In stack overflow, a user can add his/ her participation information in the profile. They call it stack overflow user flair (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60724/how-do-i-add-the-stack-overflow-profile-icon-to-my-blog), I was wondering whether ROS answers have anything similar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275245/how-to-add-ros-icon/-flair-to-my-profile-or-website?/) by [balajithevoyager](https://answers.ros.org/users/30029/balajithevoyager/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2017-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Answers is an instance of [AskBot](https://askbot.com/). According to [support user flair?](https://askbot.org/en/question/3033/support-user-flair/) it doesn't support what you're looking for.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1